# Full calendar data not showing in previous button click

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar to show Attendance of students per month . When i click on previous button data loads correctly but the values are not showing in my calendar. I can view the date in console but not in the calendar

```
$(document).on("click", ".fc-prev-button", function () {
    getMonth();
});
$(document).on("click", ".fc-next-button", function () {
    getMonth();
});

function getMonth() {
    var date = $('div[id*=calendar1]').fullCalendar('getDate');
    date = date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    alert(date);
    $('div[id*=calendar1]').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: "{Date:'" + date + "'}",
        url: "attendance-full.aspx/GetEvents",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Done");
            console.log(data);
            events: $.map(data.d, function (item, i) {
                var event = new Object();
                event.id = item.EventID;
                event.start = new Date(item.StartDate);
                event.title = item.EventName;
                return event;
            })
            $("#calendar1").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            debugger;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure what your `getMonth()` is intended to do, but Fullcalendar automatically handles loading and re-rendering new events when you change months.  If all you are trying to do is update the displayed events after changing months, you can delete most of your code, and just use the following.

Initialise your calendar, including where to get your events:

```
$('div[id*=calendar1]').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events: "attendance-full.aspx/GetEvents",
});
```

That's it!  Fullcalendar will query your event source URL when the calendar is first initialised, and then again any time you change month or view.  It will automatically re-render new events - you don't need to write code to manually do that.

Every time Fullcalendar queries the event source, it will pass `start` and `end` parameters, so your server-side code should use those to determine what events to return.  It looks like your code is using `Date` - you should either update your code to us `start` and `end`, or you can [use `startParam`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/startParam/) to change `start` to `Date` (though you probably want to use `end` too).

The Fullcalendar docs are good, you should read through them.  Check [the event source documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/), and look through [some of their examples](https://fullcalendar.io/).

Comment: @Dont't Panic Can i pass the first date as start and last date as end . Thank you for your support i am just a beginner in full calendar

Comment: @Jks I am not sure what you mean.  Fullcalendar already passes `start` and `end`, automatically, for the currently visible range.  Open up your browser's developer tools, and watch the network tab - you will see what Fullcalendar is doing, and the parameters it passes when you change months/views.

Comment: can i pass values that a user specified . for example a values between 10/09/2017 -15/09/2017 , Sorry i cant vote for you because i don't have enough reputation

Comment: There is no way for the user to specify dates that are displayed, only to pick a view and navigate it.  When they do that, the start/end are automatically determined by the displayed range.  If the user clicks 'previous month', the new dates are automatically sent.  If you mean when the user clicks on a day or event, you could fire a separate AJAX call in the `eventClick()` or `dayClick()` callbacks.